# Echo Cancellation over Voice Telephone Network

Tags: adaptive-filters

I'm a bit confused about the way echo canellation over a voice telephone network works like in the following figure
[image]

My issue is with the fact that the point of the adaptive filter and LMS algorithim is to drive the error e(t) to zero correct?
Then surely, Speaker B would hear nothing as the algorithim converges.

Comment: think about what your $e(t)$ represents.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It repersents the unechoed, original speech of speaker A that I want speaker B to hear right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A usual arrangement of echo cancelers in a full-duplex system is shown in the following figure (from *Digital Communication* by Lee and Messerschmitt):

[image]

The echo cancelers try to remove any residual transmitted signal in the receiver of the same end. Since the input to the echo canceler is the transmitted signal, it can only remove signal components in the received signal that are correlated with the transmitted signal. It cannot remove any other signal components, such as the signal that is transmitted from the far end (which is the desired received signal). Consequently, the error signal can never become zero, and the desired signal (transmitted from the other end) will not be influenced by the adaptive filter.

Comment: Ah. That makes so much more sense. Thank you so much.